# AS3: How to pass object as an argument to array.indexof

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3, object, point, indexof

Consider an array p consisting of objects m of type Sprite. How do we pass an object that we want to check is in the array to p.indexof( m? ) ?. This code:

```
p=stage.getObjectsUnderPoint(new Point(ball.x, ball.y)); 
if (op.indexof(myClass.m) >= 0) { speedX *= -1; speedY *= -1; }
 p.splice(0); //empty p
```

Comment: can you give more code? You have to pass an object which is of the type of the objects contained in the array. Not sure I understand.

Comment: Assuming p (you have "op" in your conditional...) is an array, that is exactly how you do it. It doesn't matter what data type you try indexOf with; as3 simply loops through the array and does a logically equal to test ( `array[i] == obj` ) and returns the index if it is. Your code should work just fine, assuming the array isn't null.

Comment: As the others have said, you got some 'splainin to do Lucy. This doesn't make much sense. Either your array contains the objects you put in it, or it don't.